# Re-open a crashed explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, crash, taskbar

How do I open Explorer again after it crashes? Opening Task Manager and adding "explorer" as a task simply opens up a new instance of My Computer but does not open the taskbar etc.

Additionally, no existing processes of explorer are running in the process list.

Comment: What is your operating system

Comment: Windows 7 32-Bit

Answer (score 3):

If it has crashed, you may need to close the existing process before you open a new one.

Before typing "explorer" into the Task Manager -> Run window, go to the processes tab and make sure Explorer.exe isn't still hanging around after the crash. If it is, end the process and then run explorer again.

Answer (score 0):

most common cause is malware... get combofix.exe from bleepingcomputers.com and run it. Save logs and SHARE here. You are best advised to get expert support but anyone can run it. Only issues are many settings are restored to default for Windows. Best trojan remover & free. But again.. post results.

Accept all prompts when running (pref in safe mode) and it takes 15 minutes avg.

Answer (score -1):

From the Task Manager (Ctrl + Alt + Del) Go to file > run... Then just add the ".exe" to explorer

In the processes tab, make sure that explorer.exe isn't running. if it is, select it then press end process, then click agree to the confermation that comes up.

Comment: Windows-R won't open the Run box if explorer is crashed.

Comment: So could the problem be that I'm trying to run "explorer" and not "explorer.exe"?

Comment: I don't have a 7 box to check this on right now, but I just confirmed that in XP Windows-R will not open when explorer is crashed. This is because the Windows-R keystroke is monitored and acted upon by the explorer process. Also, you do not need to type the full "explorer.exe". "explorer" is sufficient so long as there are no other executables named explorer in any of your paths.

Comment: Just tried and explore.exe produces the same result.